# select all options in html select dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, html-select, form-submit, multi-select

I have two HTML selects in a form. The first is called `available` and contains several options:

```
<select name="sortedby" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="start">
        <xsl:if test="@sortedby='start'">
            <xsl:attribute name="selected">true</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        Start time
    </option>

    <option value="thread_id">
        <xsl:if test="@sortedby='thread_id'">
            <xsl:attribute name="selected">true</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        Thread Id
    </option>

    <option value="user_name">
        <xsl:if test="@sortedby='user_name'">
            <xsl:attribute name="selected">true</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        Username
    </option>
</select>
```

The second is called `yourselection` and is empty at the beginning:

```
<select name="sortedby_target" multiple="multiple">
</select>
```

There is a button which removes the selected options from `available` and moves them to `yourselection`.

This button calls a JavaScript function from a library that I can use but can't modify.

Basically it works fine. But there is a minor inconvenience: When the user moves one or several option(s) from `available` to `yourselection`, they are not selected by default "upon arrival". So currently the user has to select an option first in `available` than move it to `yourselection`, and again manually select it in `yourselection`, and then submit the form.

What I want is everything that arrives to `yourselection` should be marked as selected by default. Any ideas?

**UPDATE!** I have a function that can select all elements:

```
function selectAllOptions(obj) {
    if (!hasOptions(obj)) { return; }
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.options.length; i++) {
        obj.options[i].selected = true;
    }
}
```

But the question is how to call it? I do not want to add another button for that reason.

There should be something like `onfill` or something similar in select.

Comment: Sure, some suggestions come to mind, like setting the selected property on the moved elements, but all we see is a bunch of serverside code that's not really relevant to the javascript at all ?

Comment: "setting the selected property on the moved elements" how?

Comment: How should I know, I haven't seen any code related to the question ?

Comment: How are you moving the elements? You need to give code.

Comment: not really relevant to the javascript at all. I have no access to this javascript function. I can use it, but I am not allowed to modify it. I can write a different one, but then what should call this new function?

Comment: We still need to see it, otherwise it's impossible to tell when, how and what elements the function moves, and where they move to ?

Comment: please find updated question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    <form name="jmxForm" onsubmit="selectAllOptions(sortedby_target)">
    ....
    </form>





function selectAllOptions(obj) {
if (!hasOptions(obj)) { return; }
for (var i=0; i<obj.options.length; i++) {
    obj.options[i].selected = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one **UPDATED!**

HTML

```
<select name="sortedby" multiple="multiple" id="sortedby" onchange="putvalue()">
    <option value="start">Start time</option>
    <option value="thread_id">Thread Id</option>
    <option value="user_name">Username</option>
</select>

<select name="sortedby_target" id="sortedby_target" multiple="multiple" ></select>
```

SCRIPT

```
function putvalue(){
    $('option[value="' + $('#sortedby_target').val() + '"]').prop('selected','');
    $("#sortedby_target").append('<option value="' + $('#sortedby').val() + '" selected>' + $('#sortedby').val() + '</option>');
    $("#sortedby option[value=" + $('#sortedby').val() + "]").remove();
}
```

I apologized for my first solution hopefully this helps.

If you want to be selected all the selected items, remove this line

```
$('option[value="' + $('#sortedby_target').val() + '"]').prop('selected','');
```

Comment: what should call this function?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit" onclick="selectAllOptions(sortedby_target);" />
```

or

```
<form onsubmit="selectAllOptions(sortedby_target);"></form>
```

You can get inspired here:
http://demo.redmine.org/projects/asdf/issues
when trying to change columns in a table.