# JavaScript n PHP w/ Select Boxes

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, forms

Example is [here](http://www.chenetwork.org/test.php).

I'm moving countries from one select box to another, when I submit the form I want the values in the right text box to be used by php.  When I give the right box a name for a php array, like ToLB[] the Javascript fails.  How can I handle this so that the submitted values will be used by php processes?

[image: Screen Shot of Web Page]

Comment: some code would help... but the basic answer would be once all the options are set in the selections made, onsubmit-ing the form loop though all the options and make them selected, or store the options in a list and pass it to the processor page. Depends on your implementation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147077/select-all-options-in-html-select-dynamically

Comment: If the right box is inside the form, just give it a `name` attribute and it will be sent. And in Javascript select the element by `ID` not `name`.

Answer (score 0):

in forms it's a typical process to use an action and a method. This is declared within the form tag. For example

```
<form name='phpSend' method='post' action='myActions.php'>
```

Now when your form is submitted it is instantly 'posted' to the url myActions.php and is automatically declared as a $_POST array.

The names of the inputs become the array keys and the value becomes the value.

A basic method is to do a procedural action. Meaning if you leave the action attribute blank, the action will submit the form to the page you're already on and use if statements to check if the form has been submitted.

```
if(isset($_POST)&&isset($_POST['someName'])){
    //form submitted!
}
```

Now, I've never used a multiple select before so you may want to `var_dumb()` or `print_r()` your output to double check but my guess is it'll be an Array within the $_POST array.

Submitting with javascript

```
if(document.getElementByName('phpSend').submit){//or however your checking
    var selected=[];
    for(var e=0;e<document.getElementByTagName('select').options.length;e++){
        if(document.getElementByTagName('select').options[e].selected==true)selected[e]=document.getElementByTagName('select').options[e].value;
    }
//then add the selected array to your preferred method of sending your data to your php document
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replies.  And they're right on target for a simple text box or a single select item. With multiple select the select box, posting to php,  the select box is named "ToLB[]" with an open and closed bracket on the end of the name.  When this is submitted it tells php that it is an array of all the items selected.  When I do with this code the javascript fails.

Comment: @JamesS.Null The reason it fails is there's obviously a syntax error caused by the brackets. If you're submitting your form from javascript, submit the select as an array :)

Answer (score 0):

I often encounter a situation like this and I usually submit the select options as a string.
Add an hidden field to your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="valuesToSubmit">

<script type="text/javascript">
var selectobject=document.getElementById("myselect");
var myValues = "";
for (var i=0; i<selectobject.length; i++){
myValues = myValues  + selectobject.options[i].value + ",";
}
document.form.valuesToSubmit.value=myValues;
</script>
```

In the PHP scripts that receive the posting data you can use the explode function to turn your sting into an array and then iterate on it ... depends what you need to do. Remember to remove the last unwanted ","

Comment: Thank you ... just not seeming to get it all working together.  the code is too long to post here but it can be seen at www.chenetwork.org/test.php

Comment: Thank you ... just not seeming to get it all working together.  the code is

Answer (score 0):

I have taken a look at your code.
There are some missing parts and amendments to do to make it works.
I didn't test the amendments but I think they should work.

1)you have to add the hidden field inside the form.

```
<form name="combo_box" action="test.php">
<input type="hidden" name="valuesToSubmit" value="">
```

2)Then you have to give the id to the select box because you use the id to reference the object like this var selectobject=document.getElementById("ToLB");

```
<select multiple size="10" name="ToLB" id="ToLB" style="width:150">
```

3)Change th submit button with a normal button so you can force the submit only when the loop is ended and the values have been passed into the hidden field.

```
<input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"  onClick="updateValues()">
```

4)Force the submit at the end of the javascript

```
function updateValues(){
    var selectobject=document.getElementById("ToLB");
    var myValues = "";
    for (var i=0; i<selectobject.length; i++){
    myValues = myValues  + selectobject.options[i].value + ",";
    }
    document.form.valuesToSubmit.value=myValues;
    document.combo_box.submit();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I adjusted this at www.chenetwork.org/test.php ... values move from one box to the other, but when I submit the page does nothing. Ideas???