# How to set size for selectOneMenu box

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml

i cannot find an answer on google. I have a select box and i want to expand the input field to have a select box stretched by at least 3 rows. I know that with html it's just a simple 'size="3"' but the project i am working on is using primeface - xhtml and the selectbox is as below

```
<p:selectOneMenu  id="areas" value="#{beanMb.item}" class="form-control" style="width:100%;" required="true"  >
       <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
       <f:selectItems value="#{anotherbeanMb.itemSelectItem}" itemLabel="anotherbeanMb.itemSelectItem.descricao" itemValue="anotherbeanMb.itemSelectItem.codArea" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: "expand the input field to have a select box stretched by at least 3 rows" What you mean exactly here? Did you mean the filter option in selectOneMenu?

Comment: something like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28180092/javascript-n-php-w-select-boxes

Comment: @ThanigaiArasu for html its like you can do this: <select size="3">

Answer (score 0):

PrimeFaces does not use a `<select>` element to render the `p:selectOneMenu` component, try using a css style to define the `min-height` of the div that contains the list of elements
something like this:

```
div[id$="areas_panel"] .ui-selectonemenu-items-wrapper {
    min-height: 100px !important;
}
```

Comment: It is indeed a `select` element wrapped within other `div`s with PrimeFaces CSS classes. Inspect your `p:selectOneMenu`'s generated HTML using developer tool and search for the div with `ui-helper-hidden-accessible` above `ui-selectonemenu-label`, which is your selected value.

Comment: @ParkashKumar that is just a helper, to do changes over that element will not affect what the user is seeing in the `p:selectOneMenu` component , the actual list that the user sees in the page is the one under the div I describe in my answer